# Stop WooCommerce New Order emails being sent for each language

Tags: woocommerce, wpml, woocommerce-bookings

I'm using WooCommerce with the WooCommerce Bookings extension and WPML. I have 4 languages on the site, and each time a new booking comes in I receive 4 "new booking" emails and 4 entries are placed in the bookings calendar.

At the bottom of the email is a link under:
*You can view and edit this booking in the dashboard here:*

Each email has a different link corresponding to each language.

Is there something I can do to only receive these emails and calendar entries for the default language?

thx!

Comment: You should ask very active and awesome WPML support instead…

Comment: Check the compatibility of WooCommerce Bookings with WPML.

Comment: Thanks, guys, I've spent the last couple of months with WPML and Woo Bookings support and not coming up with a solution. The outcome has been: WPML are saying it's intended behaviour and Woo Bookings are directing me to WPML.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec any ideas as to why this might be happening? I'm not getting any leads from WPML as they are saying it's intended behaviour, but I'm sure emails aren't meant to be sent for each instance of the booking per language or calendar entries being made. Thanks for your help!